# Maverick server overwrite apache files

Tags: apache, osx-mavericks, server

I need to alter configuration of Apache 2 in my Maverick server for rewrite module (AllowOverride FileInfo instead of AllowOverride None).

I am doing it there

/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/sites/0000_any_80_.conf

It's working great, but when I restart, the server overwrite this specific file...
So I started to change it everywhere else :

/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/sites/0000_any_80_.conf
/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/sites/0000_any_80_.conf.default
/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/sites/0000_any_80_.conf.prev

Again at restart it clean that file... I found another location of that file thinking that this is the original model

/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/etc/apache2/sites/0000_any_80.conf.default

Which I also modified but at restart it still restore my file...

I cannot understand how is that possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After battling hours I finally concluded that Server.app overwrites at binary level this setting.

So to change the AllowOverride property you need to do it through GUI of Server.app, once you click on the desired website you can check that parameters. So it's impossible to set AllowOverride to FileInfo, with a checkbox you have only 2 choices, None or All...

[image]